# How should we react to questions from users that cannot provide clear feedback?

Tags: discussion, questions, bad-questions

<s>Say as an example the following question: [How can I get the mail servers from a horde webmail without been the domain owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160910/how-can-i-get-the-mail-servers-from-a-horde-webmail-without-been-the-domain-owne?noredirect=1) (I hope it does not get deleted as a proof of my point)</s>

This is not a good example of my point, because this question is off-topic. I am referring to on-topic questions.

**How should we react in scenarios where the OP's limited knowledge leads to failing to provide  clear feedback?**

In those scenarios where the OP is asking about something where in order to answer it we need the OP to know other more basic concepts, and this is not the case, what should we do?

When the user's question is trivial, this is not a matter of importance (we can jsut answer the question). However, when the answer is non-trivial (it requires interaction from the user), he won't be able to communiate, thus the question remaining unanswered, and deviating answerers from high quality questions.

Comment: I have drastically updated my question to make a clear point.

Comment: Yes, that is what a Chameleon question looks like.  You invalidated Makoto's answer, not good.  Just click the Ask Question button again.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry for that; I was not clear on how to ask the question. Probably the reason it was downvoted. Do I edit it back to how it was and ask a new question?

Comment: It seems you demand interaction, even though the proper way to move ahead is obvious.  Hehe.

Comment: Click the "edited 4 hours ago", find the version of the question you want, click "rollback".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question demonstrates a lack of understanding of certain core concepts necessary to understanding the answer to that question, then treat the question as asking for an explanation of those concepts, in addition to what it's actually asking.

For many situations, that means the question will end up becoming "too broad".  If explaining the concepts that are clearly not understood would be beyond the scope of what can be in an SO answer, then vote to close the question as Too Broad.

If it simply means adding an extra sentence to your answer, or maybe even a short paragraph, then add that paragraph to your answer, so that the concept is understood.

Note that if the question requires information from the author in order to even come up with a solution (let alone explain it) then that question has other problems entirely.  It's unclear, or lacking a reproducible example, or an adequate description of the problem, etc.  Close it accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

The question you see is simply off-topic for the site.  There's no need to elaborate on any other detail than closing this question as a question which might be best suited on Super User.

Experience doesn't really matter here; everyone started off as a rookie doing this.  People are asking questions *because* they're rookies, or are confused by a certain aspect of software.  We don't shun people because of their experience (or lack thereof).

What we *do* deal with is off-topic questions, and this is simply and clearly off-topic.  VTC as such.

Comment: I'm not referring to being a rookie about a certain aspect of software; I'm referring to not being able to communicate with the OP with common technical jargon.

Comment: I simply cut the chase and decided that the question wasn't suitable for the site.  There's no need to delve any deeper than that.  The question seems to be a *reasonable* question (e.g. how do I get email on my phone), but isn't a question that Stack Overflow should be answering.

Comment: OK, the example that I've found may not be the best, but my intention is to refer to the issue in general. My point is, I was trying to tell the user how to find the SMTP domain name but I failed to completely communicate with him. Him not knowing how to do so would not be a problem, as it might not be if your question is, say, related to functions.

Comment: ...problem was (and would be) when the OP can't understand the steps you are taking in your explanation.

Comment: I maintain my position on this @J.C.Rocamonde.  The question is off-topic.  That's the only thing that matters at this point.  Closing it and getting it over to Super User (or at least informing them that Super User is a *better* fit for their question) is the only energy that needs to be spent here.

Comment: To the general question - perhaps instead of communicating with heavy jargon, you could simplify what it is you're explaining.  If you ever find yourself needing to use unconventional phrases to explain to someone how to do something, *perhaps* it's not their lack of knowledge on the matter, but your ability to communicate it to them?

Comment: To put an analogy, it's like if someone asks you "What is a static method in a class used for? [in Python]" when they do not know what is a class. There is nothing wrong with the OP not knowing either thing. However, in order to understand the answer, maybe he needs to learn about classes in Python. No matter how much you simplify jargon, you _have to_ mention classes (because it is what the question is about).

Comment: From that question I can't glean that they don't know what a class is.

Comment: Haha you know I was trying to put an __analogy__. I'm trying to take you a different scenario see if you understand my question here. I assumed _that_ question is no good example.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde:  I'm confident I understand your question, but I remain *adamant* that it's a non-matter in the face of an off-topic question.  Even if the question *were* on-topic, them not understanding protocols or jargon isn't *really* our niche.  We can simplify our explanation of it.  If they don't understand what they're working in, we can't realistically *help*; we're not meant to be teaching those concepts to them.

Comment: I have drastically updated my question to make a clear point.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde:  See [Exit Strategies for Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/175248).